# Use PHP loop to fetch tables data from the table which contain names of database tables

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I have table named **category** which contain names of other tables in the same database. I want to fetch table names from ***category table*** and then fetch data from each table from db. So far I have this code below:

```
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_cat');
    if($db){
    //    $q = "SELECT TABLE";
    //    $echo = $db->query($q);
    //    echo $echo;
    // $result = $db->query("SHOW TABLES");
    $qCat="SELECT * FROM product_category";
    $cat_query= $db->query($qCat) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($fetch=  $cat_query->fetch_object()) 
    {
    $cat_id=$fetch->id;
    $category=$fetch->category;
    $p_cat=str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($category).'_categories'); 
    //if(strlen($category)>22){$fine_product_name=  substr($service, 0,19).'...';}else{ $fine_product_name=$category;}
$result = $db->query("SHOW TABLES");
       while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
            $tables[] = $row[0];
    }
    }
```

Comment: And where is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The second query must be different.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $category"); 
   while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $tables[] = $row[0];
}
print_r($tables);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your design to connect to a database is not that good, Please check the below code for a proper way of connecting to it.

```
    <?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_cat"); 

//servername,username,password,dbname

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySql: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }

?>
```

Here is a sample code of getting data from a table ( where this table name is in another table).

```
 $get_table_name ="SELECT TableName FROM table_name";           
    $get_name=mysqli_query($con,$get_table_name);
    $count=0;

    while($row_name=mysqli_fetch_array($get_name)){

        $count++;
        $tbName=$row_name['TableName'];             
        $_SESSION['table_name'][count]=$tbName;

    }
```

This will show you how to fetch data from one table. You can use a For loop to get all the tables

```
 $table=$_SESSION['table_name'][1];

    $get_table ="SELECT * FROM $table";

    .... // Normal way of fetching data
```

You can try to adjust your code according to this and improve it.

For further reference please refer http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Please show me sample of for loop for this Code @VihangaBandara